# On the definition of linear tranformations being similar

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. 
Let $L,T$ be two linear maps from $V$ to $V$. What is the definition of 'two linear transformations $L$ and $T$ are similar'?

I am a bit confused because I only know similarity for matrices. I first thought that linear transformations $L$ and $T$ are similar if and only if perhaps the underlying matrices $[L]$ and $[T]$ are similar with respect to some choice of basis of $V$. But then that just means $L$ and $T$ are the same maps...

I did a quick search on the internet but I couldn't find what I was looking for. I would greatly appreciate clarification!
Thank you very much!